# How to determine what executed a script in the browser?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I wrote a simple [web app](https://github.com/shanemcandrewai/smdb-ace/blob/src-noconflict/docs/index.html), which employs the [Ace front end editor library](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/v1.4.12/src-noconflict/ace.js) to open a JSON file see [demo](https://shanemcandrewai.github.io/smdb-ace/). While debugging, I noticed a script [mode-json.js](https://shanemcandrewai.github.io/smdb-ace/ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-json.js) is executed but in the call stack I see only `(global)`.

[image]

`console.trace()` shows only -

```
<anonymous> http://localhost:3000/ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-json.js:1
```

The results are similar in both Chrome and Firefox

How would I determine who the caller is?

Comment: Throw an error instead of using console.trace and see if you get more information? Also: which browser are you testing in, because not all browsers report the same stack trace for functions on a timer (interval/timeout).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am using Firefox 92.0. I added the line "error" to the top of mode-json.js and I receive -  xxx net.loadScript ace/mode/json ace.js:3786:10
Uncaught ReferenceError: error is not defined
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-json.js:1
mode-json.js:1:1
xxx afterLoad ace/mode/json

Comment: I thought so, FF is (unfortunately still) not great at stack tracing detached functions. Check this in Chrome, it tends to give much better stack traces for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I appreciate your help. I installed Chrome and the Call Stack shows one row `(anonymous) mode-jso.js:1`.  I then added the line "error" to the top of `mode-json.js` and console shows `mode-json.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: error is not defined
    at mode-json.js:1`. Any ideas?

Comment: Please work that approach and your findings into your post, because that's not what the comments are for. You're not strictly speaking talking "to me", you're talking to "folks on SO asking for information/suggesting things to do", which allows you to update your post with all the details relevant to your post.  In this case, I'd certainly also recommend heading over to https://github.com/shanemcandrewai/smdb-ace/issues and asking _them_ what they think might be wrong. Because it's their code, they are _the_ authority when it comes to things that don't work.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans https://github.com/shanemcandrewai/smdb-ace is my own repository but it depends on the [Ace editor libary](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/tree/master/src-noconflict). I received some [feedback](https://groups.google.com/g/ace-discuss/c/aIQ0j2nMWw4) on a similar question to the Ace forum but my question is really how would one determine the caller at runtime

Comment: The most efficient way in the absence of actual error information would be to run through the [mcve] exercise: copy your code to a new dir, and start removing code that isn't related to the problem at all, then start incrementally removing lines of code until the problem no longer occurs (either because it doesn't get triggered, or things suddenly work), then restore what you just deleted, and follow that codepath.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Just to be clear - I don't have a specific bug - my goal is to understand to how to determine what triggers a dynamically called script in general. In this case, the library uses [Document.createElement()](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/v1.4.12/src-noconflict/ace.js#L3388)  to insert a script tag in the HTML document header, then sets `src` to be the script's URL and finally executes it. Am I correct in assuming this can only be determined by reading the source code? Is it not possible to see such dynamically inserted script tags in the  stack trace?

Comment: The stack trace stops at the top of the call stack, so if you insert a script element and then that runs something that immediately errors out, and you're hoping to get the error to go all the way up to the line of code that inserted the script (or even higher), you won't be able to do so, because the script insertion doesn't go wrong: that part succeeds, and if you inserted it into the head, a completely new JS run pass occurs, with a run stack that's independent of any other code that's active.

Comment: That said: your comment _pretty completely changes the question_ so it'd be worth updating the post: if you're trying to get an error to "jump the divide" caused by inserting a script into the DOM, and that script getting executed causing an error, that is a very different question than what is currently in your post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237258/discussion-between-user2309803-and-mike-pomax-kamermans).

Comment: Instead, please let's update the post to be exactly about what it needs to be, and then we can delete all the comment that got us to that point. No need for chat here: starting a chat is a sign that you're trying to talk to a single, specific person, which is the opposite of the aim when posting to Stackoverflow, where the whole point is that _everyone_ on the site can write an answer to your post.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. My answer would be - In case the script is dynamically calling external scripts by inserting <script> tags at runtime (which is true for the given example) - there is no debugger / tool which can indicate how the external script is called. The only way it to grep the source looking for `createElement` or similar and then manually check the source code. However, I can't see how I could make the question clearer, can you?

Comment: Yeah: you can delete all the text that you have in it right now, and instead ask the thing you're talking about here in the comments: you have a script that you're creating on the fly and injecting with a DOM append to the head; that injected script throws an error; is there a way to trace that error to the line of code that performed the DOM injection.

Comment: but there was never an error. I was just trying to understand how an external script module was called by a third party library. I discovered the DOM injection by reading the library source code which is kind of laborious. I suspected there was a easier way but was wrong apparently. Did you assume I wrote DOM injection myself?

Comment: I did (not an usual thing depending on the kind of thing one works on).

Comment: I have updated my question, is it clearer now? If it was my own code, then I would already know who the 'mysterious' module caller was. I notice this pattern is not uncommon in the javascript world, [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#mechanics) uses a similar technique. I doubt I am the first one to be puzzled by this seemingly spontaneous script invocation. It's a shame there is no tool which could pin point the DOM injection or whatever that invokes a given script

Comment: I'd strongly urge you to update the text just a little more to not just link out, but explain those links too - imagine all those links becoming 404s: the question on SO should still make sense, and be answerable by someone reading it. That said: I'm pretty sure that "right now" this is the best we get, but browsers have changed a lot in their debugging capabilities over the years and it might make sense to even just file a bug on the chromium issue tracker and mozilla's bugzilla to hopefully get someone to implement "across-injection" stack tracing.

Comment: I have revised the question, is it clearer now?

Comment: Unfortunatley I'd have to say no: really try to write your post as if there's no such thing as external sites to look at, and remember [not to post "pictures of code"](/help/how-to-ask). Describe what you see happening: you have code that uses ace, _you_ wrote the following code (and then your own [mcve] code made), and when you run it there is an error with surprisingly little information (and then you show the error), and then you explain how you tried to debug it, how that didn't work, and what you'd now like to know (i.e. "can I even get more information" / "how does one trace further")

Comment: You have mentioned an error several times now, what error?